# Comma between adjectives?

Tags: orthography, adjectives, coordination

Is it okay to separate adjectives with a comma? Since my sentence has three adjectives, I added them just like how we would in English to separate a list containing three or more items (no comma if the list contains only two).

> 彼の彼女は綺麗で、親切で、背が高いです。
>
> His girlfriend is beautiful, kind, and tall.

Is there an equivalent rule regarding comma usage in Japanese?

Comment: I am more concerned about your adjective order of "physical-mental-physical" than the use of commas in Japanese, regarding which there are no written rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [basic rules](http://bunsyou.net/kouza1/12toten.html) about the use of commas in Japanese but these are not absolute.

I think a writer can use commas as they like to make a sentence easier to read.

And I don't think there is a clear rule in Japanese as you say.

Comment: I agree with this. I've been told there aren't really any rules for Japanese. You kinda more or less just put them wherever you think the speaker/reader needs a pause, like you said.